# Building Unity xCode project with dsym files causing errors

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, debug-symbols

I'm trying to build a Unity project for iOS with xCode 5.1.1 while maintaining a set of dSYM files should I ever need to read a crash log. Building with the setting 'DWARF with dSYM file' in Debug Information Format is causing an error to appear. And yet the app still builds fine. Is this something I should be concerned about? Does this error suggest the dSYM files are invalid? The error is invalid abbreviation code [114].